# Parsing Arraylist XML from web service using jquery (.NET Framework 2.0 - No upgrade allowed)

Tags: jquery, .net, xml, arraylist

I have gone through a lot of forum thread but still stuck before posting this.
We are still using NET Framework 2.0, not plan on upgrading.

I have created a web service returning arraylist.

```
` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.onsemi.com">
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">ANNUAL</anyType> 
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">SEMI-ANNUAL</anyType> 
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">QUARTERLY</anyType> 
  </ArrayOfAnyType>`
```

My xml parsing code is as below

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    url: "Webservice url",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (response) {
        $(response).find("ArrayOfAnyType").each(function () {
            var data = $(this).find("anyType").text();
            alert(data);
        })
    },
    error: alert("Error")
});
```

I am getting the below result:

First pop-up message display "Error"
Then a second pop- message display "ANNUALSEMI-ANNUALQUARTERLY"

I want the result to "ANNUAL", "SEMI-ANNUAL", "QUARTERLY", each different pop-up.

Not sure if I have all info posted, please let me know if still lacking info.
Any positive advice is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I managed to get the result myself.

$( document ).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
          url:"web service url",
            dataType: "xml",
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                xml = response.documentElement.childNodes;
                for (i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {
                    value = xml[i].nodeTypedValue;
                    alert(value);
                }
            }
        });
    });

Comment: how do i tag as answered?